# Mercurial wrapper directory around a codebase

Tags: mercurial

Our team is moving to mercurial (from SVN).  None of us has a lot of experience setting up a central server for push/pulls.

In subversion our top-level directory is currently "codebase" and within it we have all the usual suspects...

```
codebase  <- subversion root
- .svn
- src
- docs
- etc.
```

For our central hg server, we've setup a top-level wrapper folder that's the hg repository and then, within that, we put the "codebase" folder.  So the Mercurial dir structure looks like this...

```
dev  <- mercurial root
- .hg
- .hgignore
- codebase
  - src
  - docs
  - etc.
```

Note the the new hg server will *not* be preserving any of the .svn artifacts.  The intent with the wrapper folder isn't to "wrap" an svn repo.  The code has been exported out of the original svn repo and is just a "new" hg codebase.

I can't see any advantage to using the top-level wrapper folder but the team has a soft-opinion that its a good idea.  I still can't see the reason for it.

Can anybody here provide some guidance on why the "wrapper" folder might be a good or bad idea?  To me it just seems like an unnecessary nesting that makes things a tiny bit more irritating (from the command-line particularly).

But maybe there's some advantage I'm just not understanding?

Thank you!

-Gary

Comment: Are your src, docs, and etc. directories independent? If they are, you may want to make each its own hg repository.

Comment: If they want to have a wrapper folder because it's a good idea, you can always say "hey let's not have a wrapper folder because it's a better idea".

Answer (score 4):

The only advantage I see to wrapping `codebase` is that you can do hg commands from `dev`. If you dump files at the same level as `codebase`, that might be worth while. Otherwise, it looks like a waste of a directory to me.